# How to save array variables in antoher array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am making question like 3 * 5 = ? and ? * 5 = 15. To make this, I will save an array variable ($arrayTotalQuestions) with the number 1 to 10 and an array variable ($arrayAnswers)
with the number 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50 inside $array1. I will loop these 2 rows 20 times in my table like this:

```
foreach($array1 as $array1) {
    echo $array1[array_rand($array1)];
}
```

The (array)variables inside the array:

```
$arrayTotalQuestions = range(1, 10);
$number = 5;
$arrayAnswers = (5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50);
```

Now I want to store these 3 variables inside another array named $array1:

```
$array1 = array(
    "<tr><td>$this->arrayTotalQuestions</td>    <td>x</td>     <td>$this->number</td>     <td>=</td>      <td><input type='text' name='txtAnswer[$this->arrayTotalQuestions]'></td></tr>",
    "<tr><td><input type='text' name='txtAnswer[$this->arrayAnswers]' value=''></td>   <td>x</td>  <td>$this->number</td>   <td>=</td>  <td>$this->arrayAnswers</td></tr>"
);
```

But I am getting the error "array to string conversion...", because of the array variables inside $array1.
How can I solve this?

Comment: what do you want the name of your input tag to be?

Comment: Do you want those array variables inside that $array1?

Comment: Your question is completely unclear

Comment: yes, I want to store those array variables inside $array1

Comment: But still unclear, can you please show required output and update your question?

Comment: why are you storing HTML like this?

Comment: question is updated

Comment: Why even make the questions like that? Why not just make the calculation on the fly and output one question. Why add lots to an array?

Comment: I only want to know how to fix this

Comment: The error is because of $this->arrayTotalQuestions is an Array. If you want to output all Elements in that array in your td Theben you can implode the array. E.g. implode(',' , $this->arrayTotalQuestions). But not sure if this is what you want

Comment: No, I want to output only one element per td.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says you're trying to convert an array to a string, which isn't possible.

Take a look at this example:

```
<?php
  $array = [1,2,3,4,5];
  $newVar = "This is my array: $array";
?>
```

This results in the error `E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Array to string conversion -- at line 3`.

You're trying to output an array, which has multiple values in it, as part of your string. PHP doesn't know how you want to do this (should it just list all the array vars? Does it put a space between them? A comma? A comma and a space? etc)

So, instead, you need to convert the array into a string yourself. One way you can do this is to use the `join()` function in PHP.

`join()` takes 2 parameters: `separator` and `array` and outputs a string which is all the array values separated by your separator.

So the above example becomes:

```
<?php
  $array = [1,2,3,4,5];
  $newVar = "This is my array: ".join(", ", $array);
?>
```

Which outputs `This is my array: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

---

### Updated based on comment

To use 2 or more arrays in the same foreach loop you just need to change it into a for loop:

```
for($i = 0, $i < count($array1); $i++) {
  echo $array1[$i].': '.$array2[$i];
}
```

There is a way to do it with a foreach loop too, but I find that this isn't quite as clean a way to do this for maintenance (just my preference).

```
foreach($array1 as $index => $value) {
  echo $value.': '.$array2[$index];
}
```

Comment: I want something like this:

an output like this:
test 1 and 40
test 2 and 70
test 3 and 100
test 4 and 10
test 5 and 40

by doing this:
    `$array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $array2 = [10,20,30,40,50, 60, 70, 80, 100];
    foreach($array1 as $array1) {
        echo "test $array1 and". $array2[array_rand($array2)];
    }`

I want to use array2 too in the loop of array1

Comment: Added to my answer in reply to this comment @cbk38. You need to use a for loop, rather than a foreach loop.